# Create React App build doesn't render all elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I am running into a weird issue with create react app.

I am building an application and it all looks fine when running `npm run dev` :

[image]

Where the button texts are coming from an API call.

Then I tried it with a production build, so I ran `npm run build` followed by `serve -s build` and that all went fine, console told me to go to http://localhost:5000, which I did, and then it looks like this:

[image]

So suddenly my buttons aren't visible. But the weirdest thing is: they are definitely still there. I can hover over them, see my mouse turn into a pointer, and I can still click them. I even get the console.logs that I have on every button, and they print out the title of the button, like they are supposed to do.

I checked the console on http://localhost:5000, there are no errors. I also get the proper response back from the API, so that works as well. The network tab doesn't show me any errors either; all files are loaded correctly (html, js, images, css, you name it)

I have tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, all of them have this issue.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Can you provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any debugging details you done? Seems React is rendering the component fine and your problem is in the browser, i.e. what style/CSS is applied against the DOM.

Comment: If you could, can you please edit your question to include that basic root component rendering the `content-wrapper` div and children, and the CSS styles. It would be a better and more complete question, which would be more helpful for anyone landing here in the future.

Comment: I'll also be able to change my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

I seems you've set the `opacity` to a really low value and the questions div is *nearly* invisible.

```
#questions.visible {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1%;
}
```

## Solution

The [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) value is typically a value between 0 and 1, though percentages appear to still work (within Chrome at least). Based on the base CSS rules I assume you meant to make this value `1` when applying the `visible` class.

```
#questions.visible {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Apply the same for your chat area

```
#chat-area.visible {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that was indeed the issue. I put it on 100%, as I thought that was the correct value and it works on local development. But when building it it seems this gets parsed as 1%, for whatever reason. Now indeed I just put it as 1 and it works.